# Openssl error while updating composer, and getting error when disabling

Tags: php, laravel

I am running composer update and getting this error:

```
The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl ex
  tension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.
```

and after I disable it I get another error:

```
You must enable the openssl extension in your php.ini to load information from https://repo.packagist.org
```

(I also tried it by enabling openssl from PHP.ini, I get the same errors)
Does anyone know what the problem is?